# Implementing StrretView App by Google in my project but have difficulties in understanding

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7MWw.png)

**
i want to implement this design layout in my project but i am having difficulties in implementing and understanding.This is the picture of street view app by google . Please help me to implement.**
the link is mention above :

Answer (score 0):

Add fragments to your layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you check the link which i have mentioned above

Comment: yeah i did... You can add multiple fragments in your layout a/c to your requirement. change your layout to relative layout and add fragments to different place holders

Comment: i try alot it will be really helpfull if you give me some practical example.